# Can't Access Private MySQL Docker Image From Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, dockerhub

I've been trying to pull in a private (custom) MySQL image from my Docker Hub repository to the gitlab-ci.yml pipeline as a service. I have added a before_script that tries to log in to dockerhub with my username and password (CI variables). There's no output in the failed build log suggesting whether the login to Docker Hub was successful or otherwise but I'm assuming not because the pulling of my image fails with the following message (edit: or it's never even attempted because gitlab tries to get the services before it runs the before script?):

repository does not exist or may require 'docker login' (executor_docker.go:168:0s)

I am using a shared runner (because I believe that's my only option using gitlab.com?)
I've seen quite a few mentions of the gitlab ci token for docker but I've found no documentation explaining how to facilitate this.

I'm sure I'm just overlooking something/not understanding or coming across the appropriate solution in my searches so apologies if I'm just being inexperienced and thanks in advance for any help.

My gitlab-ci (the maven variables are because this project's build has a dependency on a private maven repo. The database and redis host variables are injected into my app at runtime so they know which container to point to)

```
image: maven:3.5.0-jdk-8

before_script:
  - "docker login -u$DOCKER_USER -p$DOCKER_PASS" #pipeline variables

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
  DATABASE_HOST: mysql
  REDIS_HOST: redis

services:
  - name: privaterepo/private-mysql-schema
    alias: mysql
  - name: redis:latest
    alias: redis

stages:
  - build

maven-build:
  stage: build
  script: "mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS package -B"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First thing is to setup GitLab CI to provide credentials of the private docker registry when needed. To do that there is [specific section in docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry) you should follow, to be a complete answer that is

1. Get docker registry url, username and password using `docker login`
   or some other manner (I had to spend sometime to figure out registry for the
   docker hub)
2. Define `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` variable in GitLab CI variable section it would look like

```
{
    "auths": {
        "registry.hub.docker.com": {
            "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" // base 64 encoded username:password
        }
    }
}
```

3. Declare image/service `image: registry.hub.docker.com/ruwanka/helloworld:0.1` in `.gitlab-ci.yml`

That should full fill the requirement of pulling images. There is [another section in docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-docker-section) that lists the requirement of runner to allow list of services. If it doesn't specify any then it should be fine, you may have to tweak it if it doesn't work.

final yaml is look like below

```
image: registry.hub.docker.com/ruwanka/helloworld:0.1

build:
  script:
   - echo "hello"
# more steps   
services:
  - registry.hub.docker.com/ruwanka/helloworld:0.1
```

snippet of GitLab job's logs

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes I found this documentation and tried it. I had to generate the Auth key from my username and password as demonstrated and set it as a gitlab ci variable. It didn't work so I kind of gave up on it. I wondered if I was getting the registry URL wrong. It's a docker hub private repo so normally when I fetch images (eg in docker compose) from it all I need is "namespace/imagename" but I'm not sure what my registry URL is? Any idea? Some of the instructions seemed to suggest ways to find it out but they just looked like generic docker URLs... Thanks in advance

Comment: Either way I will vote your answer up as you are correct that that's supposed to be the way you do it :)

Comment: I think when you using docker cil it should be looking at private docker hub repos, but here we need to specify it to work in runner environment, figuring out the correct repo url was the trickiest part for me also, please consider accepting the answer if you found it useful. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying I need a bespoke runner?

Comment: In the variable i've tried as the auth url:

hub.docker.com/myHubNameSpace

hub.docker.com/u/myHubNameSpace

myHubNameSpace


but ALWAYS:
Running with gitlab-runner 11.1.0 (081978aa)
  on docker-auto-scale 0277ea0f
Using Docker executor with image maven:3.5.0-jdk-8 ...
Starting service myNameSpace/myImageName:latest ...
Pulling docker image myNameSpace/myImageName:latest ...
ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for myNameSpace/myImageName, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login' (executor_docker.go:168:0s)

Comment: I tried one more thing which was to add a 'u' like hub.dockerhub.com/u/myNameSpace to the image url and the host url in the auth variable and this time a different error : ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: Get https://hub.dockerhub.com/v2/: dial tcp 217.70.184.50:443: getsockopt: connection refused (executor_docker.go:168:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ... ** it then goes on to retry twice more and fail

Comment: I've updated the answer with docker hub private registry url that I used. You may able to tweak the runners configuration if you use you own runner.

Comment: Thanks... but it looks like you've provided 2 different urls: firstly you wrote "Declare image/service image: my.registry.tld:5000/namespace/image:tag in .gitlab-ci.yml" and then in your yml file, you've got "image: registry.hub.docker.com/ruwanka/helloworld:0.1" or same for service (i'm not trying to use my private image in image, just in service, as the main image is maven:3.5.0-jdk-8). Is "registry.hub.dockerhub.com/nameSpace" correct syntax? and should that also be used as host in auth variable? Getting really confused by the whole thing : ( I only have shared runner available fyi

Comment: sorry for the confusion, steps are just general guidelines extracted from docs (I've updated that also to reflect ci file). Please setup `.gitlab-ci.yml` as the one I provided and have the `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` as I provided. Then it should work good luck. (There is no difference for images vs services, they are just docker images)

Comment: Thanks I'll try - you should remove your hash from it asap!

Comment: Woooooooo. It works. I don't know how you figured that out because I couldn't find it anywhere online. You're a legend. Thank you :))

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to aware the bounty. I thought it was automatic when I gave the check mark but it just reminded me. Thanks again.