# gitlab-ci: How to specify the image that the job runs on?

Tags: windows, gitlab-ci

I am trying to make sense of the documentation:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#image

and in particular:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#access-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry

So I wrote the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
# https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#set-a-default-before_script-or-after_script-for-all-jobs
default:
  before_script:
    - docker login -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_JOB_TOKEN} ${CI_REGISTRY}

build windows:
  tags:
    - powershell
    - windows2022
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build
      --tag ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
      --build-arg WSCI_VERSION=ltsc2022
      -f demo/Dockerfile .
    - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_SHA}

test windows:
  tags:
    - powershell
    - windows2022
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
    - docker image inspect ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_SHA}

Upload Windows packages:
  tags:
    - docker
    - windows2022
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  stage: deploy
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  script:
    - dir
```

The line `before_script` is never called, and so the image as specified on the `image:` line cannot be accessed.

How can I login when I specify an explicit `image:` from a private repo ? It does not look like `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` has been setup in my private gitlab setup.

---

For reference, here is the error message:

```
Using Docker executor with image gitcloud.acme.com/repo/project:cd370af73fb5058cdb251262c1805fd7246c99ee ...
Authenticating with credentials from C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.docker\config.json
Pulling docker image gitcloud.acme.com/repo/project:cd370af73fb5058cdb251262c1805fd7246c99ee ...
WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "always": Error response from daemon: Head "https://gitcloud.acme.com/v2/repo/project/manifests/cd370af73fb5058cdb251262c1805fd7246c99ee": unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://gitcloud.acme.com/help/user/profile/account/two_factor_authentication#troubleshooting (manager.go:237:0s)
```

---

If I understand correctly, the correct way to access the image from the private repo is documented at:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#determine-your-docker_auth_config-data

However this documentation seems to imply that I know the password. This is not my case, as a simple user I simply use:

```
${CI_REGISTRY_USER} / ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've found in the documentation, you'll have to setup the `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` (or one of the [methods described here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#access-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry)) for your project or runner.

> However this documentation seems to imply that I know the password. This is not my case, as a simple user I simply use [the job token]

For this, you'll need to generate credentials for your private registry. In the case of the GitLab Container Registry, this is described [in the authentication documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/authenticate_with_container_registry.html), which means one of:

- [Personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html)
- [Deploy token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/index.html)
- [Project access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html)
- [Group access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/group_access_tokens.html)

You would then use one of these tokens to create your `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` variable in your project as described [in the documentation you linked](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#determine-your-docker_auth_config-data).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to sytech, I re-read the documentation and created a deploy token which seems to works in my case.

For later reference here is what I did today:

Create a [deploy token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/#create-a-deploy-token) (no username):

[image]

Update the test stage to dump the following extra value:

```
test windows:
  tags:
    - powershell
    - windows2022
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    DUMP_ENV: 'env:'
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - dir ${DUMP_ENV} # verify that both CI_DEPLOY_USER and CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD are present
    - docker login -u ${CI_DEPLOY_USER} -p ${CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD} ${CI_REGISTRY} # use the deploy token
    - cat C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/.docker/config.json # dump 
  script:
    - docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
    - docker image inspect ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
```

Now that we have the complete json, [create](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#for-a-project) the expected variable [`DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#access-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry) as:

[image]

If your deploy stage failed, simply restart the value `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` will now be properly read. Et voilà !